# Can generic indexed access parameters be constrained?

Tags: typescript

For the following type:

```js
type Union =
  | {
      type: "string";
      payload: string;
    }
  | {
      type: "number";
      payload: number;
    };
```

I can create the following function:

```js
const call1 = <T extends Union>(union: T) => {
  console.log(union.type, union.payload);
};
```

And calling it with a bad type throws an error:

```js
call1({
  type: "number",
  payload: "hi", // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
});
```

However, if I define the function using indexed access:

```js
const call2 = <T extends Union>(type: T["type"], data: T["payload"]) => {
  console.log(type, data);
};
```

Now calling the function will not throw an error:

```js
call2("number", "hi"); // no error
```

Is it possible to have the function with indexed access parameters constrain the type of the second parameter via the type of the first?

Comment: The problem here is one of inference; the compiler cannot infer `T` from `T['type']`. [ms/TS#20126](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) would've allowed this but it was never merged. The standard way of doing this is to refactor your `Union` to an interface with key/value pairs, like [this](//tsplay.dev/werzYN). Both versions technically work and fail in the same way (you can manually specify `T` in your version and `K` in my version) but inference behaves more acceptably in my version. Does this fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with [generic type argument inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  In your version of `call2()`,

```
const call2 = <T extends Union>(type: T["type"], data: T["payload"]) => {
    console.log(type, data);
};
```

You are probably expecting the compiler to *infer* `T` from the fact that `"number"` is assignable to `T["type"]`.  Unfortunately, this just doesn't happen.  The compiler does not see `T["type"]` or `T["payload"]` as good *inference sites* for `T`.  So inference fails and the type `T` falls back to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which is `Union`, as you can see with IntelliSense:

```
call2("number", "hi"); // no error
// const call2: <Union>(type: "string" | "number", data: string | number) => void
```

And since `Union["type"]` is `"string" | "number"`, and `Union["payload"]` is `string | number`, the arguments `"number"` and `"hi"` are respectively assignable to each, and no error happens.  Oops.

It's not unreasonable to expect inference to work in this case, and in fact such inference was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126), but this feature was never merged.

In cases where generic type arguments aren't inferred the way you want, you could always manually specify them yourself, like this:

```
call2<{ type: "number", payload: number }>("number", "hi"); // error
// ------------------------------------------------> ~~~~
```

But presumably you want to get inference working for you.

---

The best way to have the compiler infer a type parameter for you is to give it a value of that type.  I mean, instead of trying to infer `T` from a value of type `T["type"]`, have it infer `U` from a value of type `U`.  This means your type parameter should correspond to, say, the `type` argument of `call2()`, and then you can compute the type of `data` from that.  Since your `type` values are of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), it is easier to write the relationship between `type` and `payload` in terms of the relationship between an object key and its value.  Like this:

```
type UnionMap = { [T in Union as T['type']]: T['payload'] }
/* type UnionMap = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
} */
```

The `UnionMap` type has your `type` as its keys and the corresponding `payload` as its corresponding values.  And we computed it from `Union` using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  And now the call signature for `call2()` can be changed to this:

```
const call2 = <K extends keyof UnionMap>(type: K, data: UnionMap[K]) => {
    console.log(type, data);
};
```

So the `type` argument is of generic type `K`, which should hopefully make inference succeed, and then the compiler can check the argument passed for `data` against `UnionMap[K]`.  Let's see if it works:

```
call2("number", "hi"); // error
// -----------> ~~~~
// const call2: <"number">(type: "number", data: number) => void
```

Looks good.  The type argument `K` is inferred as `"number"`, and therefore `data` is expected to be of type `number`, to which `"hi"` is *not* assignable, and you get an error.

---

By the way, this isn't 100% foolproof.  Just as before you could get the non-error to become an error by manually specifying the type argument to be one piece of the union yourself, you can get this error to become a non-error by specifying the type argument to be the full `keyof UnionMap` union yourself:

```
call2<keyof UnionMap>("number", "hi"); // okay
// const call2: <"string" | "number">(type: "string" | "number", data: string | number) => void
```

Since `K` is `keyof UnionMap`, then that again makes `type` of type `"string" | "number"` and `data` of type `string | number`, to which `"number"` and `"hi"` are respectively assignable.

Generally speaking, nobody ever does this sort of thing, but it does technically mean that the compiler cannot necessarily assume that `K` will be exactly one of `"string"` or `"number"`.  There is an open issue asking for that at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), but for now it's not part of the language.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXgFBW1APlAbyxxNEgC4oAiAZ2ACcE4BzKgbmJOzAEMQAbJDwAmlOoxYcSAX055Cc0uAiUqcAK4BbAEYR67RTl4ChoqBp16pOaRwwYAxijpQHPfvwCM6KAB4AKlAQAB7AEHDCNLCIKAB8ABTqMXCU-gCU6LEKJE5wNEj8EAB0gsyJyUVkEAA0UEnIcEXGgiJpHLb2cDyaEDS8DtAA8ozM2Ti5Lm4eAEw+AUGh4ZHRDQlVqQDaVFVUALq1wjzAPJtUzaZ7GWhZRFzjzgXFpfFVB0c8bXIdOe780-FqLS6fS1KgACwQVDaUAA9DDzEggvR6Eh6HI4a5nMBXL9ppRfPBVi9lKpxExWPJAZYQVBDscxAxyfILMCrlkAG5IBDCew-Ga+AhQdbUFl6Ki1c4iSii+hQaQJKnA8XUCFQtgYvQotEYWQYKorFAAWR4YB8go2gSYBtQPCi-g2AHIqg7drtNg7JcIXXKMDCAFRC5TW42mtBjbBklgMiTMazYGXSoFWHVQP0w+wTbFTP5zADSCzCESiAGsICAkAAzYMmtYkqC5t706tgDa53Zs8OYvKPEpIMqvWnvT4dDO4gEy5XgyHQjXI1G++GZnEzfGKsW1igipM0uknczbjuc7mj-ml8tVwlGmvj7eT1Uz+FwRGa1G1bTqbGQJBgQpQHj0aAkn4BBS34EAhURYREWACEaAXLtJlxVdIwpfA130DcVGoFCqEpCdGz3FDmQPTIoCPYQgA)